# Continuous logic function

Tags: functions, logic

I'm trying to find a **continuous** function $f:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to \{0,1\}$, so that on the sub-domains $[0,1/2), [1/2,1]$ $f$ behaves like an AND gate (or OR gate). I don't think it can be done, because we would need to define a function highlighting a quadrant, which can't be continuous. But I don't think this is a proof that it is impossible. Any ideas?

Epilog: Is there any continuous representative for the discrete logic gates?

Motive: There is a motive for this question - Fourier analysis can be used to simulate functions (and more relevantly step functions) via sine and cosine function, in $\mathbb{1D}$. Can we simulate the usual logic gates using a $\mathbb{2D}$ adaptation of Fourier analysis?

Comment: How do you define an AND gate on real values?

Comment: If $x \in [0,1/2)$ take the input as $0$, etc...

Comment: If you consider $\{0,1\}$ as a subspace of the standard normed space $\mathbb R$, then every continuous function $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ must be constant. This is a consequence from the Intermediate Value Theorem. More topological: Since $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is connected, the image $f([0,1]\times[0,1])$ must be connected as well.

Comment: @sranthrop - is this an answer or comment?

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with logic functions, I didn't dare to write that as an answer. :)

Comment: @sranthrop: your answer is a good one - go for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider $\{0,1\}$ as a subspace of the standard normed space $\mathbb R$, then every continuous function $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ must be a constant (either $0$ or $1$). This is a consequence from the Intermediate Value Theorem.

A more topological approach is: Since $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, the image $f([0,1]\times[0,1])$ must be connected as well.

So we conclude that there is no continuous function that can be mapped to a simple, non-trivial logic gate.